# Get a TimeOnly long time string with invariant culture

Tags: c#, .net, datetime-format

I have a `TimeOnly` object in .NET 7, with the value `15` hours, `16` minutes and `17` seconds. I want to produce a long time string for it in the format of the `InvariantCulture`.

If I call `ToLongTimeString()` on it, the result is `"15:16:17"`, because that is what my current culture implies. If my current culture had instead been `"en-US"`, the result would have been `"3:16:17 PM"`. I cannot provide a culture to `ToLongTimeString()`.

If I call `ToString()` on it, the result is `"15:16"`, because that is what my current culture implies. If I instead call `ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"))`, the result is `"3:16 PM"`.

Is there a way for me to always get the result `"15:16:17"`, with seconds included, even when my current culture is e.g. `"en-US"`?

Comment: [DateTime.ToLongTimeString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolongtimestring?view=net-7.0) doesn't accept any parameters either. That method is meant to return the current locale's long time string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *generic* `ToString()` (note, that *specific* `ToLongTimeString()`, `ToShortTimeString()` and similar methods of `TimeOnly`, `DateOnly`, `DateTime` don't accept extra parameters). You can either use `"T"` format string (which stands for long time format) and specify the required culture, e.g.

```
TimeOnly time = new TimeOnly(15, 16, 17);

// Doesn't matter what current culture is, we want Swedish (Sverige) one
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sv-SV");

// Long Time format - "T" - in Swedish culture
string result = time.ToString("T", ci);
```

Or you can specify the format manually, i.e.

```
TimeOnly time = new TimeOnly(15, 16, 17);

// We want hours : minutes : seconds format
string result = time.ToString("HH':'mm':'ss");
```

Comment: It's worth noting that [DateTime.ToLongTimeString()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolongtimestring?view=net-7.0) doesn't accept any parameters either.

Comment: Implementation of public string ToLongTimeString `public string ToLongTimeString() => ToString("T");` Creating an extension method for this should be an easy one.